# How to extract data from a loop outside the loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I calculate standard deviations in a for loop as such:

```
times = os.listdir(r'filepathway')
    for file in times:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
           ...
           ...
           z = df.iloc[1004:1255,:]
           y = np.std(z)
           print(y)
```

and I get a list of values. But when I print(y) in the next cell (outside of the loop), I don't get all the values. How can I basically extract the data from the loop into the next cell?

Comment: you need to store y value from each iteration of the loop in some sort of data structure, e.g. list. Then, after the loop, print this list. Also take a look at `glob.glob()` - you can specify pattern (path/*.txt) and it will return only txt files - no need to check the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of why you can even `print(y)` is because the variable remains with the last value it had. You need to save all those values in a list:

```python
result = []

times = os.listdir(r'filepathway')
for file in times:
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
       ...
       ...
       z = df.iloc[1004:1255,:]
       y = np.std(z)

       result.append(y)

print(result)
```

Comment: @D.Kim, please, if this answer worked for you, mark it as **accepted** (the green checkmark ✓)

Comment: Yes that worked! I was waiting for stack overflow to let me accept your answer :)